# Is it possible on Firestore: get top items, and, then for each of these items, query their top subitems (in a subcollection), all in one go?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

My Firestore is organized in a way similar to this:

```
├── posts/
│   ├── post1/
│   │   ├── comment1
│   │   ├── comment2
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── post2/
│   │   ├── comment1
│   │   ├── comment2
│   │   ├── comment3
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── ...
```

Is there a way, for example, for me to query the most recent posts and, *for each* of these posts, get the most recent comments, all in one go? (i.e. without storing the post query and then creating a local "for-each" to get their respective comments.)

Ideally, I would like to go beyond that even: I would like to get the posts themselves as well, all in one go. This is useful for creating a view with a summary of the whole app's activity, for example.

I have the feeling this isn't possible with Firestore though. As far as I know, they follow the policy of not mixing together documents on different levels/(sub)collections in the same query.

I'm using Dart right now, but this question is kind of language-agnostic, I guess. I imagine a query like that to be of this shape:

```dart
ref 
  .collection('posts')
  .orderBy('date')
  .forEach()
  .collection('comments')
  .orderBy('date');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore can only return documents from a single collections, or all collections with the same name. Similarly it can only filter on data that is present in a known field in the documents that it returns.

So if the comments are in a subcollection under each post, you will need to run a separate query to get them.

A common workaround is to store the N most recent comments in the post document themselves, in addition to in the subcollection. That way your writes get a bit more complicated, but it allows you to read the data you need much more efficiently.

This type of data duplication is very common when dealing with NoSQL databases, and is one of the reasons they scale so well on read operations. To learn more about such trade-offs, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video).

Comment: But in this case, wouldn't it be only necessary for Firestore to know the top items' IDs? Maybe something like this could still fit Firestore `ref.collection('posts').orderBy('date').forEach().collection('comments').orderBy('date')`? I know this doesn't exist, but I don't think it contradicts your description, or does it? Besides, if I do, say, `orderBy('date')`, Firestore executes it despite not knowing if the field `date` is in the `posts` documents, doesn't it?

Comment: Thanks for the link on NoSQL data modeling. A lot of those techniques I had to find out how to deal through trial and error in the last few months XD